# How to assign values to a combobox

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

Ill post an image to explain it better.

[image]

So, imagine that I make a 1st search, then I make a 2nd, or 3rd, 4th..search and I want to back to my old searches.

I already have some code that saves old searches (working fine). My only problem is how to assign the values to a combobox in order to comboboxes return to an old state.

How could I start doing this?

edit:

```
$('#combos').on('change', '.combo', function() {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        if (selectedValue !== '' && $(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
            var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
            var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
            var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;
            $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('#combos').append(newComboBox);
        }
        });


var check_combo_box_values = $('#combos .combo').map(function () 
                {
                    return $('option:selected', this).map(function() {
                    return parseInt(this.value);
                    }).get();
                }).get();
```

Comment: We can't write code for something we don't know the sourcecode of.

Comment: What language are you using? Jquery invloved?

Comment: @CR41G14: Tags: JavaScript / jQuery.

Comment: Do you want to assign changed value to your combobox?

Comment: @Cerbrus, what sourcecode you mean ?

Comment: @polin, I have an array with some old combobox values, and I want to assign them to combobox and it should assume the old "state", like is in the pic.

Comment: @user1148875 I didn't get your pictures. Is it arrays or dropdown boxes?

Comment: It is dropdown, but im storing the values (after the submit) in an array

Comment: @polin, I will update question with combobox code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle how to add options to a combobox

http://jsfiddle.net/hRQqp/2/

Since you stated you had no troubles with saving the old searches, you should be able to put the pieces together

```
var dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');
var list = [
    "first",
    "second",
    "third"
];

// remove old options
while (dropdown.length> 0) {
    dropdown.remove(0);
} 

// add new ones
for (var i=0;i<list.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = list[i];
    option.value = i;
    dropdown.appendChild(option);
}​
```

Comment: `.appendChild is not a function` what could it be ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_appendchild.asp  It really is a function, it works in my example (http://jsfiddle.net/hRQqp/1/)
maybe you should post your existing code in jsfiddle and then we can see what goes wrong (propably var dropdown will be empty in your case)

Comment: I updated my example a little bit, now you can also select the value you want in the dropdown http://jsfiddle.net/hRQqp/2/